# how to show image in laravel yajra datatables?

Tags: laravel, datatable

I have this error GEThttp://localhost:8000/report/`[object%20Object]`

I want to display user image in reports table.

my controller code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
       if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Report::with('user','presidents', 'years', 'quarters', 'points')->select('reports.*');

        return Datatables::of($data)
            // ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('created_at', function ($data) {
                  return jdate($data->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
            })
          ->addColumn('image', function ($report) { 
                    $url=asset("$report->user->image['thumb']"); 
                    return '<img src='.$url.' border="0" width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />'; 
            })
            ->addColumn('action', 'action', 'image')
             ->make(true);
        }

        return view('reports.index');
    }
```

js code:

```
 { data: 'user.image', name: 'user.image',
       render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
           return "<img src=\"/report/" + data + "\" height=\"50\"/>";
     }
 },
```

Comment: Did you test that your $url variable returns a fully qualified url? In such case why not use data.image as your image url?

Comment: Yes, I tested the URL does not have a problem

Comment: Ok, but in this case is not clear for me that user is holding image, because you are adding image column to your $data collection, which is from your Report model

Answer (score 0):

I changed my controller and js code: it is work

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {
       if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Report::with('user','presidents', 'years', 'quarters', 'points')->select('reports.*');

        return Datatables::of($data)
            // ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('created_at', function ($data) {
                  return jdate($data->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
            })
          ->addColumn('user.image', function ($data) {
            return ' '.$data->user->image['thumb'].' ';
           })
            ->addColumn('action', 'action')
             ->make(true);
        }

        return view('reports.index');
    }
```

js code:

```
{ data: 'user.image', name: 'user.image',
                    render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
                        return "<img src=\"" + data + "\" height=\"50\"/>";
                    }
              },
```